# Reading info from one Binary file and writing to another binary file

Tags: c++, struct, binaryfiles

For example if i have a struct, and i have already wrote in the title to the first binary file `bfile1.dat` using `cin.getline(info.title, MAX)`.

If i would like to transfer the title from `info.title` to `transfer.title` which is tied to `bfile2.dat`, how would i go about doing so?

```
struct Information
{
   title[MAX]
}
const int MAX = 50

int main();
{
   Information info;
   Information transfer;
}
```

Comment: by copying it into transfer

Comment: Need information about the file formats of the binary files.  Please edit your post with the answer.

Comment: See [std::ifstream::read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).  Usually the `read` method is used with *binary* files.  The `getline` function is used with *text* files.

Answer (score 0):

> If i would like to transfer the title from `info.title` to `transfer.title`, which is tied to `bfile2.dat`, how would i go about doing so?

Transferring the data from `info.title` to `transfer.title` is easy.

```
transfer = info;
```

It's not clear to me what you mean by ***`transfer.title` is tied to `bfile2.dat`***.